# Error: Member not found: 'PlatformInterface verify' Flutter. After using my old project which was working fine now gives this error

Tags: flutter, package

Below is the error which i'm getting after updating my flutter version from 2.0.1 to 2.8.2(pre).

I have tried to do "flutter pub cache repair" , flutter clean and flutter pub get, it doesn't solve my problem.

Even i tried to update gradle same (no-success)

### Error

```
../../snap/flutter/common/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/url_launcher_platform_interface-2.0.5/lib/url_launcher_platform_interface.dart:37:23: Error: Member not found: 'PlatformInterface.verify'.
    PlatformInterface.verify(instance, _token);
                      ^^^^^^
../../snap/flutter/common/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/video_player_platform_interface-5.0.1/lib/video_player_platform_interface.dart:35:23: Error: Member not found: 'PlatformInterface.verify'.
    PlatformInterface.verify(instance, _token);
                      ^^^^^^
../../snap/flutter/common/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/webview_flutter_platform_interface-1.8.1/lib/src/platform_interface/webview_cookie_manager.dart:33:23: Error: Member not found: 'PlatformInterface.verify'.
    PlatformInterface.verify(instance, _token);
                      ^^^^^^
2 FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Script '/home/enbake/snap/flutter/common/flutter/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle' line: 1070

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildDebug'.
> Process 'command '/home/enbake/snap/flutter/common/flutter/bin/flutter'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
```

### Flutter Doctor

```
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 2.8.2-0.0.pre.1, on Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS 5.11.0-46-generic, locale en_GB.UTF-8)
    • Flutter version 2.8.2-0.0.pre.1 at /home/enbake/snap/flutter/common/flutter
    • Upstream repository https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
    • Framework revision d993220b44 (3 weeks ago), 2021-12-27 17:52:48 +0530
    • Engine revision 890a5fca2e
    • Dart version 2.15.1

[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 32.0.0)
    • Android SDK at /home/enbake/Android/Sdk
    • Platform android-31, build-tools 32.0.0
    • ANDROID_HOME = /usr/lib/android-sdk/
    • Java binary at: /home/enbake/software/android-studio-2020.3.1.26-linux/android-studio/jre/bin/java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.10+0-b96-7249189)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
    • Chrome at google-chrome

[✓] Android Studio (version 2020.3)
    • Android Studio at /home/enbake/Downloads/flutter_theme/android-studio-2020.3.1.26-linux/android-studio
    • Flutter plugin version 63.0.1
    • Dart plugin version 203.8452
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.10+0-b96-7249189)

[✓] Android Studio
    • Android Studio at /home/enbake/software/android-studio-2020.3.1.26-linux/android-studio
    • Flutter plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9212-flutter
    • Dart plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6351-dart
    • android-studio-dir = /home/enbake/software/android-studio-2020.3.1.26-linux/android-studio
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.10+0-b96-7249189)

[✓] VS Code (version 1.57.0)
    • VS Code at /usr/share/code
    • Flutter extension version 3.25.0

[✓] Connected device (2 available)
    • Redmi Note 8 (mobile) • 945507b9 • android-arm64  • Android 11 (API 30)
    • Chrome (web)          • chrome   • web-javascript • Google Chrome 91.0.4472.106

• No issues found!
```

Thanks for your help

Answer (score -2):

As I have asked the same question on flutter official github issue, they suggested to update plugins, cause it doesn't depends on flutter itself.

[Issue on flutter official github issues](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/96846)

so I updated the plugins still not solved.

**Then I used this command after updating the plugins**

```
flutter pub upgrade --major-versions
```

After this magical command and putting manually updates for plugins
solves my issue.

Note : this process may take time and lots of data, In my case this process download lots of data, I remember it was gradle things ...

Comment: I have the same error, any other solutions?

Comment: You must update plugins first with latest version, then the command.  This solves my problem. Don't know about any other solution.